# raster2pgsql: Strange error when creating a table

Tags: python, raster, postgresql, sql

When I try to load an ASC file into my psql setup, I get a strange error message. I have created the SQL input file via

```
raster2pgsql -s 4236 -I -C -M gis_data.asc -F public.lightning > lightning.sql
```

The parameters follow exactly this link here. When I try to load the data into pgsql with

```
psql -d database_name -f lightning.sql
```

I get the following error message:

```
BEGIN
psql:lightning.sql:2: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "lightning_rid_seq" for serial column "lightning.rid"
psql:lightning.sql:2: ERROR:  type "raster" does not exist
LINE 1: ...lic"."lightning" ("rid" serial PRIMARY KEY,"rast" raster,"fi...
                                                             ^
psql:lightning.sql:3: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:lightning.sql:4: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:lightning.sql:5: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:lightning.sql:6: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK
psql:lightning.sql:8: ERROR:  relation "public.lightning" does not exist
```

I thought that the SQL input file would instruct pgsql to create the required tables, especially since the lightning.sql file starts with

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "public"."lightning" ("rid" serial PRIMARY KEY,"rast" raster,"filename"   
text);
```

Do I need to create the tables manually?
What is the required type `raster`?
Where is the mistake I do to get the GIS data into the pgsql database?

PS: Interestingly, my `lightning.sql` file contains a strange bit sequence. Is that normal? I thought it would be a full ASCII file with SQL instructions?

BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "public"."lightning" ("rid" serial PRIMARY KEY,"rast" raster,"filename"
text);

```
INSERT INTO "public"."lightning" ("rast","filename") VALUES                            
('01000001001975ADBD4F55B53F1975ADBD4F55B5BF0000000000003BC0B4CA4C69FDFF514000000000000 ... ')
CREATE INDEX "lightning_rast_gist" ON "public"."lightning" USING gist                  
(st_convexhull("rast"));
ANALYZE "public"."lightning";
SELECT AddRasterConstraints('public','lightning','rast',TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,,
FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE);
END;
VACUUM ANALYZE "public"."lightning";
```

Was maybe the conversion not OK?

Comment: U2ros's answer works for me. For windows users, you can find these files in: "C:/Program Files/PosgreSQL/[your version]/share/contrib/[your version]/" PS: It should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to post a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create a Postgis template database via loading and executing the sql scripts: postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql, you create the basic postgis template. This adds the spatial functions, reference systems, geometry data types, **but not** the raster datatype. To add that, you have to load and execute another script: rtpostgis.sql which is located next to the other 2 files. On linux thats in /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.0.1/rtpostgis.sql

Comment: could you please explain how to load and execute rtpostgis.sql? I have the same problem and I located my rtpostgis.sql but dont know how to load and execute it.

Comment: Either run the script on the database via GUI (pgadmin3 or 4) or via psql -i script.sql

Answer (score 16):

From the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/install/) webpage :

```
-- enable raster support (for 3+)
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I'll bet most people arriving here didn't know that raster support comes from a separate extention.