# Create shapefile of raster outline using python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, polygon, vector

I want to create a single bounding shapefile polygon of valid pixels in raster data (GeoTIFF) using python.

I need something efficient as I need to do this for hundreds of rasters. I had thought of writing out a mask using simple numpy manipulation, then passing that to gdal_polygonize.py, but that will not be quick enough.  Does anyone know of a more direct way?

Comment: Are you looking for a shapefile of the bounding box of the image or a subpart of the image or is mask and the resulting polygon irregularly formed?

Comment: You can use "plugin in QGIS called Image Boundary" (as suggested in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26893/how-do-i-create-a-shapefile-showing-footprints-of-rasters/26944#26944) and then union the result to have a total boundary polygon.

Comment: @Kersten, no, not the bounding box, the valid pixels.  The image has nodata values which I want to ignore.

Comment: @faith_dur: I want to do it in python.

Comment: gdal_polyginize.py is similar, you could look there.  Docs: http://gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html.  That and clamping your valid values to 1 would give you a 'mask'

Answer (score 4):

If your rasters are likely to have irregular or rotated boundaries, you can load the rasters into postgres using **raster2pgsql**, then running the sql it generates, something like this

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -s <SRID> <PATH/TO/RASTER FILE> <SCHEMA>.<DBTABLE> | psql -d <DATABASE>
```

To do this, you'll need to make sure you create your database first, and enable to postgis extension.

e.g.

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -s 27700 "/path/to/xyz.tif" public.test | psql -d rastertest
```

Here, the database is 'rastertest' and the raster is written into its own table, 'test'.

You can then use [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_ConvexHull.html) to generate a polygon geometry of the outline. ST_MinConvexHull does the same, but excludes NODATA pixels.

```
select ST_AsEWKT(ST_ConvexHull(rast)) from test;
```

I'm not sure how the speed would compare to your proposed numpy mask solution, but it might be worth trying. I found on my laptop it generated the convex hull in 142ms for a 2000x2000, 16Mb tiff.

As you'll be doing this on lots of images, you'll probably want to script it in python (the [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) library is the best way to access postgres from python)

Comment: many thanks. So the database is just a convenient intermediary to store the shapefile contents then yeah? Not tested yet, will do this evening.

Comment: Once I got postgresql up and running (it wan't installed), I got "ERROR:  type "raster" does not exist" after running your raster2pgsql command.  Do I have to somehow add the 'raster' type in the postgis extension.

Comment: I think the latest version of postgis had raster support built in. If you're using an older version, before 2.0, [you might need to run an additional sql script to install the functions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37590/55203)

Comment: I only installed it today, so 2.1.  I saw that thread, and I can't find the additional script (rtpostgis.sql) anywhere, including online.  Maybe I need 2.2 for out of the box support.

Answer (score 3):

[rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio), [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely), and [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) together will should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio.features as features
import pandas as pd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import shape
from rasterio.transform import from_origin

dx = 1
XY = [504675.55,7695881.9]
nx = 1000 
west = XY[0]-(nx*dx)/2
north = XY[1]+(nx*dx)/2
Transform = from_origin(west,north,dx,dx)

Array = np.zeros(shape = (10,10))
Array[2:4,2:4] = 1
Array[6:9,6:7] = 2

d = {}
d['val']=list()
geometry = list()

for shp, val in features.shapes(Array.astype('int16'), transform=Transform):
    d['val'].append(val)
    geometry.append(shape(shp))

    print('%s: %s' % (val, shape(shp)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
geo_df = GeoDataFrame(df,crs={'init': 'EPSG:32608'},geometry = geometry)
geo_df['area'] =  geo_df.area 
geo_df.to_file('JustSomeRectanglesInTheNWT.shp', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

Its a similar process if you first read a .tiff using rasterio

Comment: Can you please provide an example?